# How can I receive browser notifications from Stack Overflow from changes in questions I am active in?

Tags: discussion, notifications

I would like to receive browser notifications for all regular alerts (points, new message replies) as well as for new questions (but for defined tags only). Is that possible? I can't find any documentation regarding such thing.

Comment: While SE doesn't have built in support, you can enable browser notifications when you get mentioned on [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com). You could potentially create/find a bot that can mention you for new questions with a tag you define. For the alerts, I think you may need to turn to userscripts

Answer (score 1):

At time of writing, SO has no built-in support for browser notifications.

So the simple answer is that it's not possible.

Comment: Maybe something on Stack Apps that is useful: https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/notifier

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, there's no one solution that will get all of these notifications.

For new questions in certain tags, you can get an RSS feed by setting up *"Custom Filters"* (in the right sidebar by default) for those tags.  An RSS feed is automatically generated.  If you have a browser (e.g. Vivaldi) that provides notifications for new RSS items, or likewise an extension, then that might help.